# Compare table to itself based on datetime and boolean fields

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table that I am trying to find items that are scheduled for the same start and end time and there are two Boolean fields that indicate a schedule collision.  Here is kind of what the table looks like without having excess stuff in there:

```
id | RecordNo | Starttime | Endtime | Description | Bool1 | Bool2
```

Now, these records have different `RecordNo`  but if two records have the same `Description`,`Starttime` and `Endtime` and one record has `Bool1` as FALSE and the other record  has `Bool2` as TRUE or vice versa, that would be a schedule collision.

Can someone help me with this query?

Comment: Why do the table store if it's a collision? Normally you would calculate that in a query, don't store it. I also hope that `Bool1` and `Bool2` are not the real names.

Comment: wouldn't there be a scheduling collision if the start time of one event is less then the end time of another event?

Comment: The purpose would be to find records that are different records but have the same description only on those two Boolean fields.  The real names of those fields are ARJ and ANK.  So the logic is if we have an action that has the same descriptor and two different numbers, one has ARJ and the other has ANK, return both records as a collision.

Comment: Like this: 

id | RecordNo | Starttime | Endtime | Description | Bool1 | Bool2
1    z12345     08:00:00    10:00:00  Reboot          1       0
1    z12584     09:00:00    10:00:00  Script          1       0
1    z12769     11:00:00    18:00:00  Script          1       0
1    z12348     08:00:00    10:00:00  Reboot          0       1

Comment: Just making sure I understand correctly.  If description, starttime, and endtime all match but Booleans don't match it is considered a collision?  If so, check the third part of my answer below.  If not, please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For exact same starttime and endtime collissions

```
with records as(
 select starttime, endtime from table group by starttime, endtime where count(starttime)>1
)
select recordno from table t
 inner join records r on t.starttime=r.starttime and t.endtime=r.endtime
```

but I think you may want overlapping collisions too

```
select t1.recordno 
from table t1 
inner join table t2 
on (t1.starttime between t2.starttime and t2.endtime) 
   or 
   (t1.endtime between t2.starttime and t2.endtime)
```

This is a little dangerous though because it will join every record in the table to every record in the table.  If you have 10 rows in the table it will create a 100 row set before narrowing it to the results.  For 100 rows it will create 10000 rows before narrowing to your results.

rows ^ 2

Based on your last comment maybe you would want to do the second approach based on description and different Booleans and exact times in which case get back the duplicate transactions

```
select t1.recordno 
from table t1 
inner join table t2 
on t1.starttime=t2.starttime 
   and t1.endtime=t2.endtime 
   and t1.description=t2.description 
   and t1.Bool1 != t2.Bool1
   and t1.Bool2 != t2.Bool2
```

Comment: No dice, it did not pick up anything with the third query.  But you have the right idea.

Comment: @bbcompent1 I guess I need more info.  In your example, the third query should return the 2 reboot records.  I created the table test8 on my system and ran the code above replacing table with test8.  I populated the table with the data in your example.  It returned z12345 and z12348.  My table contained starttime of smalldatetime, endtime of smalldatetime, description of varchar(50), Bool1 of bit, Bool2 of bit, recordno as varchar(50), id of int

Comment: Actually it did work, the file did not have the expected data in it.  Sorry about that.